# SSRS 2008 - reportservices.asmx not compatible with legacy app

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

We have acquired an application that was written approximately 2003. Part of the app uses SQL Server Reporting Services to generate PDFs of reports.  Basically within the app a user clicks a button, modifies parameters (start/end date) and a report is passed back (i think) in PDF format so that it can be printed.  Great.  Works fine in SQL 2005.

However, SQL 2008 is another beast entirely.  I can run the same report from the web interface (http://127.0.0.1/reports/...).  But the URL doesn't work.  I dug around and found that the app is sending a call to 127.0.0.1/reportserver/reportservice.asmx.  Now it returns an empty string instead of the XML document.

Supposedly there is a 2005 compatible version called reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx but that generates a whacky SOAP error.  "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:  http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2003/12/reportingservices/Render.  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouterRequest() ....

I notice now when I try to use internet explorer and browse to 127.0.0.1/reportserver/reportservice.asmx i get a login prompt, whereas that was not the case with SSRS 2005.  I also notice that if I browse to reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx it returns a XML page which seems mostly similar to what was returned in SSRS 2005.

So obviously I am missing something.  I think since the app was created a while ago I should be using the SQL2000 version which is 127.0.0.1/reportserver/reportservice.asmx.  But I think now there is an authentication error.

Anyway.  I'm clueless.  Anyone have any thoughts?  Thanks.
We don't have the source code to the app, but I can modify the connection parameters, like I can ask it to query for ReportServiceXXX.asmx instead of ReportService.asmx

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to seeing the problem. If you look closely at the XML from ReportExecution2005.asmx you will see that it is in Soap12. Your error message shows that a call was made using method System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouterRequest, which is sending a Soap11 message. I am having the same problem, but have not solved it yet.

My two options are to either add a binding to SQL 2008 report service to accept Soap11 or modify my code to send Soap12. I am hoping for a simple config change in SQL server, but have not found it yet.